# Splunk - Create a Timechart with Stacked Columns

Tags: splunk

I have some Splunk logs that I want to visualize in a timechart. Specifically, I want a stacked column chart. My logs have the following schema:

`_time, GroupId, Action`

- `_time` - The timestamp
- `GroupId` - A unique identifier that may be shared across multiple records
- `Action` - The name of an action (i.e. 'click', 'move', 'swipe')

I want to show the number of *groups* that contain each action. This means that each column in the chart would multiple pieces. Currently, I have the following:

```
| stats
  values(Action)
by GroupId
```

This shows a list of `GroupId`s with an `Action`. However, when I put it into a `timechart`, using `| timechart stack_mode=stacked span=10m count by Action`, nothing gets rendered.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When ChatGPT or other LLMs fail you, the [official documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/timechart) is a great resource. If you consulted that, you'd realize `stack_mode` isn't actually a parameter for timechart. Or maybe if you read the error message that Splunk gave you:

> Error in 'timechart' command: Invalid argument: 'stack_mode=stacked'

Get rid of that argument entirely and you'll be in a much better position for getting data out of your search.

Secondly realize that searches are pure data manipulation. (Trying to mix concerns of how to manipulate data and how to render data is generally not a great idea). As a result, you cannot specify display options in the SPL itself. Chart options like "Render this as a stacked column chart" is the responsibility of Reports and/or Dashboards. For that part I point you to the [Visualization Manual](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.5/Viz/ColumnBarCharts) and the [SimpleXML Chart Configuration Reference](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/ChartConfigurationReference). (But also know depending on your requirements, you could render your chart in Dashboard Studio, or even outside of Splunk entirely. (API to run search & get results into other applications...))

Finally I recommend working through the [Search Tutorial](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchTutorial/) that gets you through the basics of Splunk searching & reporting.